# i have drawn some point upon touch and now i want to get event when clicked or long press that point had drawn

Tags: android

> My Activity shall draw a point when the user touches the screen. After this I want to be able to recognize things like long touches, double taps, etc etc on that Point
>   any Hep will be appreciated

```
public class PaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener{
ArrayList<ModelClass> xyCordinamteList;
Paint mPaint;
float mX;
float mY;
TextView mTVCoordinates;
Canvas canvas;
int pointerIndex;
View v;
public PaintView(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super(context,attributeSet);

    /** Initializing the variables */
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mX = mY = -100;
    mTVCoordinates = null;
    xyCordinamteList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Setting the color of the circle
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    // Draw the circle at (x,y) with radius 15
    canvas.drawCircle(mX, mY, 15, mPaint);

    // Redraw the canvas
    invalidate();
    drawSpecificPoint(canvas);
}

public void setTextView(TextView tv){
    // Reference to TextView Object
    mTVCoordinates = tv;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
        // When user touches the screen
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Getting X coordinate
            mX = event.getX();
            // Getting Y Coordinate
            mY = event.getY();
            // get pointer index from the event object
            pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

            // get pointer ID
            int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

            // get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
            int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();
            // Setting the coordinates on TextView
            if(mTVCoordinates!=null){
                mTVCoordinates.setText("X :" + mX + " , " + "Y :" + mY);
            }
            showDialog();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode){
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}

public void showDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    final TextView xTv = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.xTv) ;
    final TextView yTv = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.yTv) ;
    EditText et = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.userNameET);
    Button submitBtn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ModelClass modelClass = new ModelClass(xTv.getText().toString(),yTv.getText().toString());
            xyCordinamteList.add(modelClass);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    xTv.setText(mX+"");
    yTv.setText(mY+"");
    dialog.setTitle("Details");
    dialog.show();
}

public void drawSpecificPoint(Canvas canvas){
    //Paint paint = new Paint();
    //canvas = new Canvas();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    if (!xyCordinamteList.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < xyCordinamteList.size(); i++) {
            canvas.drawCircle(Float.parseFloat(xyCordinamteList.get(i).getX()), Float.parseFloat(xyCordinamteList.get(i).getY()), 15, mPaint);
        }
    }
    /*canvas.drawCircle(Float.parseFloat("730.0"), Float.parseFloat("530.0"), 15, mPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(Float.parseFloat("699.0"), Float.parseFloat("686.0"), 15, mPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(Float.parseFloat("562.0"), Float.parseFloat("863.0"), 15, mPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(Float.parseFloat("465.0"), Float.parseFloat("1025.0"), 15, mPaint);*/
}
}
```

The above code is my Activity

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            longClickActive = false;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (longClickActive == false) {
                longClickActive = true;
                float currentCorX = event.getX();
                float currentCorY = event.getY();
                /*float savedX = readPref.getXcord();
                float savedY = readPref.getYcord();
                float diffX = savedX - event.getX();
                float diffY = savedY - event.getY();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) <= 10 && Math.abs(diffY) <=10){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Matched!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }*/
                for (final Iterator<ModelClass> it = xyCordinamteList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    ModelClass modelClass = it.next();
                    if (Math.abs(Float.parseFloat(modelClass.getX())-currentCorX) <=20 && Math.abs(Float.parseFloat(modelClass.getY())-currentCorY) <=20 ) {
                        tipWindow.showToolTip(v);}
```